# Cakephp auth tries to call non-existant controller

Tags: authentication, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

My auth component works great except it duplicates the folder that my CakePHP lives in. For example, my entire CakePHP install is in `localhost/rh/` but when login redirects it sends the user to `localhost/rh/rh/controller`.  Any thoughts?

AppController:

```
class AppController extends Controller {

  public $components = array(
        'Session',
        'Auth' => array(
            'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index'),
            'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'index'),
            'authError' => "You are not authorized to access that page",
            'authorize' => array('Controller')
        )
    );

    public function isAuthorized($user) {
        return true;
    }

    public function beforeFilter() {
        $this->Auth->allow('index', 'view');
    }
}
```

UserController:

```
    class UsersController extends AppController {

//before filter to allow users to register
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('add'); // Letting users register themselves
}

//login action
public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
        }
    }
}
//logout action
public function logout() {
    $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}
```

Comment: What version of Cake are you using?

Comment: AD7six: cakephp version 2.3.7

Answer (score 1):

Add parent::beforeFilter(); to beforeFilter in the user controller:

```
function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->autoRedirect = false;
    parent::beforeFilter();
}
```

You can also replace the redirect with this to the login method of your user controller:

```
$this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
Auth->redirect() returns
```

for more clear idea just go to [cakephp.org link](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/neil6502/2012/07/28/auth_component_of_cakephp_demystified_part-2)

Comment: neither fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add parent::beforeFilter(); to beforeFilter in the user controller:

```
function beforeFilter() 
{
 $this->Auth->autoRedirect = false;
 parent::beforeFilter();
}
```

You can also replace the redirect with this to the login method of your user controller:
dd parent::beforeFilter(); to beforeFilter in the user controller:

```
function beforeFilter() 
{
 $this->Auth->autoRedirect = false;
 parent::beforeFilter();
}
```

You can also replace the redirect with this to the login method of your user controller:

```
$this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
```

Auth->redirect() returns the url where the user landed before being taken to the login page or Auth->loginRedirect.

Comment: Hardik: Did you even read the guys post above you?does anybody have any other ideas?

Comment: have you set document root in apache?

Answer (score 0):

There is an option in the Auth component called 'unauthorizedRedirect', which is the url Cake redirects users to when they try to access a page they aren't allowed access to.  If this is not set then Cake redirects to /{app-directory}, hence the appearance of your domain name where the controller should be.

Change this in your AppController

```
public $components = array(
    //your other components
    'Auth' => array(
        //your other options for Auth
        'unauthorizedRedirect' => 'url to redirect to' //can be in any form that Cake accepts urls in
    )
);
```